# Angular material dialog component hides all my website components

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I'm using angular 5 and angular material (latest version) and I'm trying to open a dialog from a page. When I click the button that triggers the opening, the entire website is put in blank background like if the dialog were overlaping it contents and hiding it all.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['dialog.component.scss']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

And this is the method that opens the Dialog.

```
onSubmit() {

        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
            width: '250px',
            data: { name: 'Juan Manuel', animal: 'Perro' }
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            console.log('The dialog was closed');
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
```

UPDATE:
I've seen that after the dialog is rendered a class is added to my html tag. **.cdk-global-scrollblock** I don't know why is that class added to my html tag.

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

That what's causing my error. Does someone knows why is that class on my html tag?

Comment: Check the console, it can be fire some exception, it can be component initialization issue.

Comment: nop, no errors on console the dialog opens fine but all my website is grayed and blanked out

Comment: where is the above class added. can you reproduce using a plunker?

Comment: I can't use plunker, but I've followed the tutorial from the official angular material site. And the dialog container is inside a router-outlet, don't know if that is helpful

Comment: Can you show us your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: If you are using fixed elements, like a header, and they disappear, make sure you have top/bottom styles set. ex. #header { position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 95px; top:0; }

Answer (score 37):

Easiest fix would be setting the dialog scroll strategy to new `NoopScrollStrategy` object:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
        width: '250px',
        data: { name: 'Juan Manuel', animal: 'Perro' },
        scrollStrategy: new NoopScrollStrategy()
    });
```

this will only require an extra import:

```
import { NoopScrollStrategy } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
```

Comment: I added it in `app.module.ts` directly to the `providers` as default configuration. like this: ` {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {width: '648px',  scrollStrategy: new NoopScrollStrategy()}}` . Works perfectly

Comment: Thank you so much. They should really put this in the docs and this should be the default behaviour for Mat Dialogs.

Comment: @Franco this 'default behavior' is not expected as it allows the user to scroll the background window while the dialog is open.

Answer (score 20):

In order to fully understand why `.cdk-global-scrollblock` is added to the html tag, I want to make a short description of MatDialog Scroll Strategies:

#### MatDialog Scroll Stragies

`MatDialog` component has the option `scrollStrategy`  (type `ScrollStrategy`), which determines the scroll strategy to be used for the dialog, as described in: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig

To associate the scroll strategy, you have to pass in a function, that returns a scroll strategy, to the `MatDialogConfig`:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
    scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block()
    // .. other options
});
```

By default, the `MatDialog`will use the `block` strategy, as found in the source [code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/dialog/dialog.ts#L55).

The other available strategies are `noop`, `reposition`, and `close` - as described [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/scroll/scroll-strategy.md).

---

#### `.cdk-global-scrollblock` css class

This class is added to the `html` tag when the `block` strategy is used.
It is used to block the scroll of the content behind the dialog, especially on mobile devices (iOS) - that's why `position: fixed;` is used. But when this rule is applied, the window will scroll back to the top of the screen. So there is a need to calculate the current the scroll of the window and apply it to the `html` tag.

Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/scroll/block-scroll-strategy.ts#L51), in `BlockScrollStrategy` class. I will copy some code here:

```
this._previousScrollPosition = this._viewportRuler.getViewportScrollPosition();

// Note: we're using the `html` node, instead of the `body`, because the `body` may
// have the user agent margin, whereas the `html` is guaranteed not to have one.
  root.style.left = coerceCssPixelValue(-this._previousScrollPosition.left);
  root.style.top = coerceCssPixelValue(-this._previousScrollPosition.top);
  root.classList.add('cdk-global-scrollblock');
```

---

#### Solutions

**1. The real problem is with your css**.

For sure that the values for `this._previousScrollPosition` are not correct, so double check the css rules added to the `html` and `body` tags.

I was able to replicate your issue by using the following css:

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvucu4.

This can be fixed by removing `body { overflow: auto; }`.

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvucu4-jek3zb.

If you really need `html` and `body` to take 100% of the viewport, even is the content is smaller, use the following css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
   min-height: 100%:
}
```

---

OR

**2. Set `noop` scroll strategy:**

```
import {Overlay} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

constructor {
  public overlay: Overlay
}

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
    scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.noop() 
    // .. other options
});
```

The page content will scroll, even if the dialog is opened.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvucu4-t4uwwb.

Comment: i havent used overflow auto in my body still m facing this issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvucu4?file=styles.css

its your stackblitz only, I just haven't used overflow property but it still does the same

Comment: can you put your example on stackblitz in order to take a look at the source code?

Comment: I agree with this solution. Here we should use dialog setup without change css with ::ng-deep.

Comment: I remove min-height of my body and it's work !

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Most of us would set height and min-height 100% to keep the footer at the bottom. For me the option 2 worked!

Answer (score 14):

This is due to `cdk-global-scrollblock` that is injected into the HTML `body` which will affect your components that have position absolute.

You can override it in the Angular Material theme CSS with:

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock {
    position: static;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

or with deprecated Shadow-Piercing:

```
/deep/ .cdk-global-scrollblock {
    position: static;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced same problem.
Following solution work for me,

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock{
    position: static !important;
    width: initial !important;
    overflow-y: inherit !important;
  }
```

Put it into your global css or in dialog components loacl css (you have to enable view encapsulation in case of local)

Answer (score 3):

I get with the same problem.İt looked like that in my css runtime.

https://www.resimag.com/p1/ff8da3c59ae.jpeg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBcpm.jpg)

For this, my solution was;
I import the ViewEncapsulation object in my component.You can learn how it is used and what it does.
https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-viewencapsulation-in-angular
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

After In css I wrote this code; "position: initial; width: initial; overflow: hidden;"

"position: initial; width:initial;" turn back the value that it received first.

This is my dialog.component.css;

```css
.cdk-global-scrollblock {
  position: initial;
  width: initial;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is my dialog.component.ts;

```js
import {Component, OnInit,Inject, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {  MatDialogRef,  MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: 'dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef < DialogComponent > ,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not overwrite base Angular Material Styles. You may experience unexpected breaking changes when you switch between mobile/tablet/desktop view or when upgrading your version of Angular Material. It is not a good idea, don't do it.
2. Use the Overlay injectable to get an overlay strategy, rather than creating a new instance of one using it's class. Otherwise, without additional/unnecessary work, you'd only be able to use the noop strategy.

See the screenshot below which shows how I'm using it and the other strategies which are available:

[image: Image showing how to use scroll strategies properly.]

By extending the base ScrollStrategy class, you can create your own strategies too.

Answer (score 2):

See the [API Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#) for `MatDialogConfig`. You can set `hasBackdrop` to `false`.

```
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
        width: '250px',
        data: { name: 'Juan Manuel', animal: 'Perro' },
        hasBackdrop: false
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just add this override css or scss class to fix** the background invisible issue.

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock{
    position: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For removing the blank white page background, you can use any one of the css :

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock{
    height: auto
  }

or

.cdk-global-scrollblock{
    position: static !important;
    width: initial !important;
    overflow-y: inherit !important;
  }
```

Comment: First suggestion worked fine for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the body's attribute, if the body has set `overflow-y: scroll`, you can change it to `overflow-y: initial`, it's work well in my code.