# Opening Angular Material dialog makes the parent display fade?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am implementing Angular Material Dialog in my project.
It is working, however, when I open the dialog, my other screen(parent component calling the dialog) disappears in the background. See the image, the background does not shows the content of the page. [image]

I want to implement it like its shown in the angular material website, where background is visible. (See Image) [image]

I don't understand the issue, as I have implemented it as described in the website.

Comment: Any error in console ? Can you show your code ? If you did like Material, then it shoud work [like this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bqlkvbqlgma?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Can you provide body css?

Comment: @Emilien No there is no Error in Console. Yes, I did used it as suggested in the example on website as well as stackblitz

Comment: @VladimirBozhinovski I haven't provided any CSS for dialog

Comment: The answer provided solves my issue. Thanks:)

Comment: I had the same issue and found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782890/angular-material-dialog-component-hides-all-my-website-components